# Select first column of a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, events, datagrid, focus

Hello I have a tab and a corresponding `datagrid`. The `datagrid` has rows. I am trying to get the focus on the first row and worst case scenario any row.

I have tried

```
FocusManager, datagrid.Focus(), datagrid.SelectedIndex and datagrid.SelectedItem.
```

None of these are working.

```
datagrid.SelectedItem = datagrid.Items[0] //does not work either.
```

Can anyone tell me how to get the focus on the first added row?

Answer (score 1):

Check this code, it's should work:

```
ResultsGrid.SelectedIndex = 0;
DataGridRow row =(DataGridRow)ResultsGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
if(row != null){
    row.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
}
```

Comment: ResultsGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex is obsolete. Can you use GetItemFromContainer? also the row is null after trying "row = grdPrograms.Items[0] as DataGridRow; "